# Is is possible to autorun even when value doesn't change?

Tags: mobx

For example

```
var x = observable({lastPressedKey:""});
autorun(() => console.log(x.lastPressedKey));
x.lastPressedKey = "spacebar"
x.lastPressedKey = "spacebar"
x.lastPressedKey = "spacebar"
```

I want that console.log prints "spacebar" three times. 
I can do something like this

```
x.lastPressedKey = ["space", Date.now()]
x.lastPressedKey = ["space", Date.now()]
x.lastPressedKey = ["space", Date.now()]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: @Alik I want to emulate something like events with mobx. For exampe `onkeypress = e => x.lastPressedKey = e.key` doesn't work if user press the same key twice.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an observable is to actually avoid what you are trying to achieve. However, you could change the lastPressedKey from a string to an object that includes the datetime, so it would trigger a rerender when the datetime changes even if the string stays the same.